# Create new shapefile for each unique attribute using for-loop with PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, select-by-attribute, for-loop, select-by-expression

I have a roads shapefile. In its `name` field, I'll create a new shapefile per attribute. I already got each unique attribute under `name`. The `for-loop` that iterates over the unique attributes and selects the features isn't working.

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject
 
def split_shp():
    # Parameters
    layer_name = 'bicolRoads_primary_secondary'
    field_name = 'name'
    
    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0] # road shp
    shp_index = layer.fields().indexOf(field_name) # road shp index
    unique_values = layer.uniqueValues(shp_index) # unique attributes under 'name' field

    for i in unique_values: # for-loop that iterates over the unique attributes
        dog = layer.selectByExpression('field_name=i') # selects features matching i/current attribute
        print(dog)

        #shp_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, new_shp, 'utf-8', \
        #driverName='ESRI Shapefile', onlySelected=True)
    
split_shp()
```

The result is this

[image]

Comment: You can do it in two lines: `res = processing.run("native:splitvectorlayer", {'INPUT':'/path/to/data.shp','FIELD':'unique_field','FILE_TYPE':1,'OUTPUT':'/my/folder/'})`, `print(res['OUTPUT_LAYERS'])`

Comment: @GermánCarrillo, I think this is for QGIS 2. Mine (3.10) says `QgsProcessingException: Error: Algorithm native:splitvectorlayer not found`. The current documentation doesn't also show what's the keyword nor the log when running the Split Vector Layer tool.

Comment: @GermánCarrillo, solved it. Instead of `"native:splitvectorlayer"`, I used `"qgis:splitvectorlayer"` but it saves per shapefile into a geopackage which is why I opted to make my own script instead of using the tool. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Here's the link to the documentation https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html?highlight=split%20vector%20layer#split-vector-layer

Comment: Right, the code I put in my comment is for QGIS 3.14, where the algorithm is already in C++ and accepts the output format (1: Shapefile). Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the return value from `layer.SelectByExpression` is None even if features are selected.

Try building the query like this:

```
def split_shp():
    # Parameters
    layer_name = 'ak_riks'
    field_name = 'LAN_KOD'
    
    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0] # road shp
    shp_index = layer.fields().indexOf(field_name) # road shp index
    unique_values = layer.uniqueValues(shp_index) # unique attributes under 'name' field

    for i in unique_values: # for-loop that iterates over the unique attributes
        s = layer.selectByExpression(""""{0}" = '{1}'""".format(field_name, i))
        print(s, layer.selectedFeatureCount())
        ...
```

[image]

But as commented `Split vector layer` would be easier. But if you want to do it your way `Extract by expression` might be easier than selecting then exporting.

Comment: Thank you for this! `.format(field_name, i)` is the line I kept searching for. This is really helpful. Thanks again, @BERA.